# How to store special characters in Oracle table?

Tags: java, oracle

I want to insert in a Oracle table a string representing a HTTP request, such as:

```
a=5&b=hello&date=2016/01/01
```

Here my Java code:

```
//HttpServletRequest request comes in to the server
String url = request.toString().substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (URL) VALUES (?)");
stmt.setString(1, url);
stmt.executeQuery();
stmt.close();
```

Currently, this string is automatically stored as follows:

```
a=5&b=hello&date=2016%2F12%2F31
```

that is, as UTF-8 encoded string.

Is there a way to store it "AS IS" rather than in URL encoded form?

Thanks

Comment: You sure that request.toString() did not do the conversion?  That is a perfectly valid set of characters for default oracle character set.

Comment: Why are you calling `toString()` on the `HttpServletRequest`? That seems like a bad idea to me. (Also "UTF-8 encoded" isn't the same as "URL-encoded".) It seems to me that this has nothing to do with the database side of things - I suggest you look at the `url` variable, and I suspect you'll find you've already got the `%2F` in there.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm calling toString() because request is a HttpServletRequest object and I need only a part of the URL

Comment: @Fab: So use the right calls from `HttpServletRequest` - in this case, it sounds like you want `getQueryString()`.

Answer (score 2):

The string is URL encoded, you can use [`URLDecoder.decode( urlstring, encoding )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) to decode it before passing it to the database:

```
String url = URLDecoder.decode(
               request.toString().substring(beginIndex, endIndex),
               "UTF-8"
             );
```